# MATLAB: Combine two cells of arrays

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I have two cells which contains arrays, and I want to combine them:

```
A={[1 2 3],[],[10]};
B={[],[33,2,1,3,1],[3,4,1]};
```

I want `C={[1 2 3],[33,2,1,3,1],[10,3,4,1]}`.

Is there a nice method that does not involve a for-loop over all elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cellfun` to go through and horizontally concatenate all of the cell array entries.

```
C = cellfun(@(a,b)[a b], A, B, 'Uniform', 0);
```

Comment: oh wonderful. i've seen cellfun before but am not experienced enough to use it. i should defintivly play with it and get used to it. Well - in any way, thank you, that's exactly what i need.